# Integral of a delta with boundary at zero

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I am trying to compute the following integral:
\begin{align}
    \int_{-\infty}^{0} d\eta_1\int_{-\infty}^{0} d\eta_2 \, e^{ix_1 \eta_1} e^{ix_2 \eta_2} \partial^k_{\eta_1}  \delta(\eta_1- \eta_2)
\end{align}
where $k$ is the order of the derivative. The extreme of integration at $-\infty$ is to be considered as $-\infty (1-i\epsilon)$.
For $k=1$, I think this is the result:

$
    \int_{-\infty}^{0} d\eta_1\int_{-\infty}^{0} d\eta_2 \, e^{ix_1 \eta_1} e^{ix_2 \eta_2} \partial_{\eta_1}  \delta(\eta_1- \eta_2) \\= \int_{-\infty}^{0} [d\eta_2 \, e^{ix_1 \eta_1} e^{ix_2 \eta_2}   \delta(\eta_1- \eta_2)]^{\eta_1 = 0}_{\eta_1= -\infty} -  \int_{-\infty}^{0} d\eta_1 \int_{-\infty}^{0}d\eta_2 \, (ix_1) e^{ix_1 \eta_1} e^{ix_2 \eta_2}   \delta(\eta_1- \eta_2) \\= \theta(0) - \frac{ix_1}{i(x_1+x_2)}
$

For $k=2$,

$
    \int_{-\infty}^{0} d\eta_1\int_{-\infty}^{0} d\eta_2 \, e^{ix_1 \eta_1} e^{ix_2 \eta_2} \partial^2_{\eta_1}  \delta(\eta_1- \eta_2) \\= \int_{-\infty}^{0} [d\eta_2 \, e^{ix_1 \eta_1} e^{ix_2 \eta_2} \partial_{\eta_1}  \delta(\eta_1- \eta_2)]^{\eta_1 = 0}_{\eta_1= -\infty} -  \int_{-\infty}^{0} d\eta_1\int_{-\infty}^{0} d\eta_2 \, (ix_1) e^{ix_1 \eta_1} e^{ix_2 \eta_2} \partial_{\eta_1}  \delta(\eta_1- \eta_2)
$

I compute the second term as before.

I get stuck in the first term:

$\int_{-\infty}^{0} [d\eta_2 \, e^{ix_1 \eta_1} e^{ix_2 \eta_2} \partial_{\eta_1}  \delta(\eta_1- \eta_2)]^{\eta_1 = 0}_{\eta_1= -\infty} = \int_{-\infty}^{0} d\eta_2 \,  e^{ix_2 \eta_2} [\partial_{\eta_1}  \delta(\eta_1- \eta_2)]_{\eta_1 = 0}$

I could think of it as:

$
\int_{-\infty}^{0} d\eta_1 \int_{-\infty}^{0}d\eta_2 \, e^{ix_1 \eta_1} e^{ix_2 \eta_2} \delta (\eta_1)\partial_{\eta_1}  \delta(\eta_1- \eta_2) 
$

But it does not seem very helpful.

Comment: Does $\int_{-\infty}^0$ means $\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^0$ ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have corrected.